# Sphinx-build generates empty content

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a documentation project in ReStructured text, which is built with sphinx-build. Among my rst files there is one that is technically correct (no warnings), added to toc, but for some reason sphinx-build generates an empty HTML from that rst. Other files are generated normally.

Attaching this file for experts to maybe advise something.

```
 [1]: https://pastebin.com/LucB2bpC
```

Comment: It turned out that 'search' is somewhat restricted word for Sphinx. You can't name your rst 'search'. When I renamed it to 'searchtab' everything worked.

Comment: If you found the solution, post your own answer below and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that 'search' is a special name in Sphinx. You can't name your rst 'search'. When I renamed it to 'searchtab' everything worked.

See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#special-names.